# AXI stream slave

Tags: fpga, vhdl

I have question about the AXI stream transfer. In the AXI stream slave, I want to capture the data coming through the AXI_Slave_TDATA and then process them (for example multiply each byte of data by 2) and then further transfer it as stream to another IP. 
What is the VHDL code which processes the stream of data entering the AXI_Slave Stream and then transfer them as stream to another IP?
Any example would be helpful

Comment: I think you will need to add more information. Particularly since the processing example you give is so trivial (shift the data bits, no logic involved). What IP do you have already for this protocol? Do you have any experience working with this protocol already?

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at the Xilinx AXI-stream IP example design.

In Vivado, open a new empty project. Tools -> Create and package a new AXI ip. And go through the wizard.

When asked, choose "Create a new AXI peripheral". This will generate example code for you for what an AXI peripheral looks like and create a barebones project to start from.

Answer (score 1):

Until you provide more details, the only answers that can be provided are about AXI stream in general.

Transfers in AXI stream take place when tvalid and tready are both high, with tvalid being driven from the source and tready being driven from the sink. When your core is ready to receive data, set tready high and read in fresh data when tvalid and tready are high. To send data, drive tvalid high along with the new data. Hold the data constant and tvalid high until you get a high level on tready. Then either drop tvalid or place new data on tdata. If you want to use a framed protocol, mark the last transfer of the frame with high tlast. Make sure to only transfer tlast when you transfer tdata (only accept or update when both tvalid and tready are high).

Comment: I have a data stored in the DDR, I want to read the data from it using the DMA through M_AXI_MM2S port and then send the stream from the DMA through M_AXIS_MM2S port to my AXI stream slave of my IP. In my IP, I want to capture the streaming data coming through the S_AXIS_TDATA and then do some calculations on them and then send them back as stream to the DDR through the S_AXIS_S2MM port of the DMA.

Answer (score 1):

You have posted several FPGA and PL implementation questions. The problem is that these questions are complex and are not easy to answer. I would suggest you to watch several dozens of Xilinx video tutorials just to have a general idea of how things work and what should be expected. Then, there are hundreds of datasheets like [UG761](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/ip_documentation/ug761_axi_reference_guide.pdf) that you can read and get your answers from. Use Xilinx DOC Navigator. Dive into it.

You are asking for an example - I bet there is one somewhere in the documentation - and it is not as simple as two lines of code. Follow these [series of videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Dt8rWJdiJo) - the guy focuses on PS-DDR-DMA transfers and gives an introduction to AXI4 interface.

Comment: I watched all the videos you mentioned and understood completely how the DMA works and the AXI protocols. I did not post several FPGA and implementation questions. My question was just how to process a stream data to custom IP and then forward them to another IP. Thanks Alex for the explanation which is totally clear. My question if there is simple example to translate the explanations into VHDL. you know there are some issues we have to take into account like the delay for 32 cycles after resetting the IP....etc.